# How to query this (snow flake) data schema in django

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I want to query a snow flake data schema in django and cannot get it right.

**model.py**

```
class City(models.Model):
   city_name =       models.CharField(max_length=30, default='')

class CityTranslations(models.Model):
   language =        models.CharField(max_length=2, default='--')
   city_name_trans = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='')
   city =            models.ForeignKey(City)

class Doctor(models.Model):
   doctor_name =     models.CharField(max_length=30, default='')
   city =            models.ForeignKey(City)

class DoctorTranslations(models.Model):
   language =          models.CharField(max_length=2, default='--')
   doctor_name_trans = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='')
   doctor =            models.ForeignKey(Doctor)
```

Short explanation:

```
Doctor  n:1  City
City    1:n  CityTranslations  
Doctor  1:n  DoctorTranslations   #e.g. german, russian, arabic
```

I want to:
1. get all fields of all tables (`selects * from`)
2. receive a list of all doctors 
3. with russian translations

So I tried:

**views.py**

```
a = Doctor.objects.select_related(doctortranslations__language='ru', citytranslations__language='ru')
```

But this ends with an error

> select_related() got an unexpected keyword argument 'doctortranslations__language'

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: When passing variables to a function you need to use `=` and not `==`, `==` is for comparison.

Comment: thanks. I changed it and an error remains. I updated the question.

Comment: Ok, I missed that one, change `select_related` for `filter`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did that and now I have: Cannot resolve keyword 'citytranslations__language' into field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Doctor.objects.filter(doctortranslations__language='ru', 
                      city__citytranslations__language='ru')
```

Comment: Could you explain a bit more, please? "City" has no field "language". So "city__language" should not exist...

Comment: Sorry I fixed my answer, can you try it now?