# django to snowflake connection and running ORM queries

Tags: django, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am looking to shift out of Postgres to SnowFlake as some of my features require run time analysis which is faster in Snowflake.

I could only get the Python connector API for Snowflake which would require me to create raw queries instead of Djago ORM queries.

Is there anyway we can connect to Snowflake using Django and execute the same Django ORM queries on Snowflake.

I saw this old post
[How to query this (snow flake) data schema in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33659966/how-to-query-this-snow-flake-data-schema-in-django/49715330#49715330)

But couldn't find how to set up a django connection with Snowflake.

Comment: That post you linked to is referencing snowflake _schemas_, a data architecture design. Not "Snowflake" the data warehouse company. See here: https://www.guru99.com/star-snowflake-data-warehousing.html

I'm also curious about using Snowflake with Django, but haven't found anything yet on this.

Comment: Would be interesting to hear what you ended up with...

Comment: Hey guys - checking in at Mar 2021 to see if anyone has a new solution to this?

Comment: 2022: There's a great package for this, by Tim Graham https://github.com/cedar-team/django-snowflake

Answer (score 1):

The [snowflake-sqlalchemy](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/sqlalchemy.html) package provides connecting from sqlalchemy to Snowflake.

Another python snowflake low-level connector is documented [here](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/python-connector-example.html)

I never tried either of them though.

Comment: @Nate this might be interesting for you

Answer (score 1):

2022 update: There's now a Snowflake backend for Django funded by
Snowflake customers and implemented by Django's [Tim Graham](https://techytim.com/):

- https://github.com/cedar-team/django-snowflake

From their docs:

### Install and usage

Use the version of django-snowflake that corresponds to your version of Django. For example, to get the latest compatible release for Django 3.2.x:

```
pip install django-snowflake==3.2.*
```

The minor release number of Django doesn't correspond to the minor release number of django-snowflake. Use the latest minor release of each.

Configure the Django DATABASES setting similar to this:

```json
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django_snowflake',
        'NAME': 'MY_DATABASE',
        'SCHEMA': 'MY_SCHEME',
        'WAREHOUSE': 'MY_WAREHOUSE',
        'USER': 'my_user',
        'PASSWORD': 'my_password',
        'ACCOUNT': 'my_account',
    },
}
```

---

Some of the discussion while implementing it:

- https://groups.google.com/g/django-developers/c/po9dS-2h4lg/m/UeKBoL8dBgAJ?pli=1

---

(Trying to mark this question/answer as duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/70935067/132438)