# How to connect to snowflake database from Django framework

Tags: django, database-connection, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm new to Django and I'm trying to display the result that comes from a Snowflake database. I know that Django has multiple built-in database backend engines like: `django.db.backends.postgresql` and `django.db.backends.mysql` among the other few it supports.

Unfortunately, I couldn't find a proper way of configuring a database backend engine in the

> settings.py

When I enter `sqlalchemy` or `snowflake-sqlalchemy` as the engine, I get this error:

```
Try using 'django.db.backends.XXX', where XXX is one of:
'mysql', 'oracle', 'postgresql', 'sqlite3'
```

My guess was to go with `sqlalchemy` as that's what I usually use to connect to Snowflake outside of Django but for some reason, it's not working properly.

I'd appreciate any guidance on that.

Comment: I believe that sqlalchemy is the way to go with Django. When you say it's not working properly, are you receiving errors or is Django just not doing what you expect?

Comment: I'm getting this error: `Try using 'django.db.backends.XXX', where XXX is one of: 'mysql', 'oracle', 'postgresql', 'sqlite3' `

Comment: Last I checked there was no support directly with django and Snowflake, but I have seen recommendation elsewhere to use SQLAlchemy https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/sqlalchemy.html or django_pyodbc or

Answer (score 3):

2022 update: There's now a Snowflake backend for Django funded by
Snowflake customers and implemented by Django's [Tim Graham](https://techytim.com/):

- https://github.com/cedar-team/django-snowflake

From their docs:

### Install and usage

Use the version of django-snowflake that corresponds to your version of Django. For example, to get the latest compatible release for Django 3.2.x:

```
pip install django-snowflake==3.2.*
```

The minor release number of Django doesn't correspond to the minor release number of django-snowflake. Use the latest minor release of each.

Configure the Django DATABASES setting similar to this:

```json
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django_snowflake',
        'NAME': 'MY_DATABASE',
        'SCHEMA': 'MY_SCHEME',
        'WAREHOUSE': 'MY_WAREHOUSE',
        'USER': 'my_user',
        'PASSWORD': 'my_password',
        'ACCOUNT': 'my_account',
    },
}
```

---

Some of the discussion while implementing it:

- https://groups.google.com/g/django-developers/c/po9dS-2h4lg/m/UeKBoL8dBgAJ?pli=1

Answer (score 2):

You should install a custom `Snowflake` engine like the following ones. Note that, as of today, those are incomplete. Though, it should not be difficult to implement missing `Django` features by completing the `operations.py`file.

-> https://github.com/pricemoov/django-snowflake

or

-> https://pypi.org/project/django-snowflake-backend/

Comment: I'm actually the author of Django-snowflake-backend and happy to help anyone in need!

Comment: Great to see you here @Ben! How would you compare `django-snowflake-backend` with `django-snowflake`? (https://stackoverflow.com/a/70935067/132438)

Answer (score -4):

```
please install snowflake-connector-python .E.g. below
pip3 install snowflake-connector-python==1.8.1
Here is the code to connect from SQL Alchemy.

=====================================================================
#!/usr/bin/env python
from snowflake.sqlalchemy import URL
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine(URL(
    account = 'XXXX',
    user = 'XXXX',
    password = 'XXXXX',
    database = 'XXXXXX',
    schema = 'XXXXXX',
    warehouse = 'XXXXX',
    role='XXXXXXXX',
))




try:
    connection = engine.connect()
    connection.execute(
        "CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE test_async(c1 TIMESTAMP_NTZ,c2 VARIANT)",_no_results=True)



finally:
    connection.close()
    engine.dispose()

=========================================================================
```

Comment: This does not solve OP's problem of making Django use Snowflake